# Displaying SQL Query Results in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to MVC 5 with .net

Basically I'm just trying to get my bearings and I want to display some generic queries (disregard the fact that im using the master db, I just want to get the functions working right now).  I'm using the authentication 2.0 which has an applicatindbcontext, but I created my own context but since I'm not really wanting to create a model (which could be the problem) I didn't know what to create for properties:

```
public class MasterModel : DbContext
{
    public MasterModel() : base("MasterDatabaseConnection")
    { }
}
```

I created the controller like:

```
public class MasterController : Controller
{
    private MasterModel db = new MasterModel();
    // GET: Statistics
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetVersion()
    {
        string query = "SELECT @@VERSION AS Version";
        IEnumerable<MasterModel> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<MasterModel>(query);

        return View(data.ToList());
    }
}
```

And finally I'm trying to figure out how to display the results in the view...and I'm completely lost (although it's possible I was lost in one of the previous steps).

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.MasterModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@WTF.Am.I.SupposedToPutHere
```

I've followed some tutorials where I've created CRUD style model view controllers, but I guess I'm not drawing the connection on how to just submit informational queries and display the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Context:

```
public class MasterModel : DbContext
{
    public MasterModel() : base("MasterDatabaseConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<MyModel> ModelOBJ { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<ModelOBJ>().ToTable("tblModelOBJ");
    }
}
```

Create a Model:

```
Public cLass MyModel
{ 
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

Public cLass MyModelRepository
{ 

   public List<MyModel> GetALlModelFromDB()
   {
     MasterModel md = new MasterModel();
     return md.ModelTosend.toList(); 
   }
}
```

In your Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyModelRepository().GetALlModelFromDB());
    }
```

In your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.MyModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   @:<div>@item.ID   @item.Name </div>
}
```

Comment: Now your Life will be Dam Easy.. Every time you want to create new module.. Just add table in DB .. provide name in Context and then add model and repository and return to View from Controller by calling repository method....

Comment: Thanks Zohaib!  I created a MasterDBContext (nevermind the Master naming, I'm just connecting things logically in my own mind)  I then created the MasterModel per your spec 'code' public string Version { get; set;}, then a view and it worked great.  Can you clarify what you meant by adding a new module and putting the name in the context and repository?  I couldn't get the ModelRepository to work as I couldn't find the ModelTosSend() function?  Thanks again

Comment: dear i mean to say i you want to create another view or a complete new Module. Then you have to add new Dbset in dbContext class and Add Model and create repository and then call that method in controller. its so simple..
no extra code no time waste

Comment: I get it. Thanks for the explanation, it makes perfect sense now and yes that does make my life easier :)  Cheers